# How do I get the Silverlight player to work in Mediaelement.js?

Tags: mediaelement.js

I'd like to add the Silverlight player to the list of players in the multi-codec support HTML since I'd like to serve up WMV files in addition to the other supported codecs, but I don't see much documentation on the website for enabling the Silverlight version other than launching it via JavaScript.

I'm at a bit of a loss, since I've tried a few variations of what I've posted below and haven't had any success.  I've looked through the mediaelement-and-player.js source, but nothing jumps out at me as to what I need to do in HTML.  Does anyone have any suggestions / tips on what I need to do to get the HTML based Silverlight version working?

If this can't be done via HTML, that's ok too - but please provide a clear example.

Many thanks,
Jim

```
<video width="320" height="240" poster="poster.jpg" controls="controls" preload="none">
<!-- MP4 for Safari, IE9, iPhone, iPad, Android, and Windows Phone 7 -->
<source type="video/mp4" src="myvideo.mp4" />
<!-- WebM/VP8 for Firefox4, Opera, and Chrome -->
<source type="video/webm" src="myvideo.webm" />
<!-- Ogg/Vorbis for older Firefox and Opera versions -->
<source type="video/ogg" src="myvideo.ogv" />
<!-- Optional: Add subtitles for each language -->
<track kind="subtitles" src="subtitles.srt" srclang="en" />
<!-- Optional: Add chapters -->
<track kind="chapters" src="chapters.srt" srclang="en" /> 
<!-- Flash fallback for non-HTML5 browsers without JavaScript -->
<object width="320" height="240" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="flashmediaelement.swf">
    <param name="movie" value="flashmediaelement.swf" />
    <param name="flashvars" value="controls=true&file=myvideo.mp4" />
    <!-- Image as a last resort -->
    <img src="myvideo.jpg" width="320" height="240" title="No video playback capabilities" />
</object>
<object width="320" height="240" type="application/x-silverlight-2" data="silverlightmediaelement.xap">
    <param name="movie" value="silverlightmediaelement.xap" />
    <param name="flashvars" value="controls=true&file=myvideo.wmv" />
    <!-- Image as a last resort -->
    <img src="myvideo.jpg" width="320" height="240" title="No video playback capabilities" />
</object>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I needed to specify that the file was of type video/wmv.  If anyone else runs into this, you can probably add something like

```
 <source type="video/wmv" src="myvideo.wmv" />
```

to the list of formats.

I'm using an HTML template engine (Velocity) and putting the type in on the fly, so the video-for-everybody may end up being slightly different.

Comment: A couple things to keep in mind when using mejs (I'm finding this out the hard way)...  If the browser doesn't support `<video>`, and you don't have flash/silverlight, then it creates a link to the file, using the poster.  That's wonderful.  Unfortunately, if the browser does support `<video>`, and you don't have flash/silverlight, then it displays a big black box with an itty-bitty white link to download the file.  I doesn't say that you need a plugin.  I'm looking through the js to see if I can add some of that functionality.

Comment: It may be worth noting that the mime type of wmv is actually `video/x-ms-wmv`.  I'm not sure why they are using `video/wmv` in the javascript.

Comment: Apparently, the black box with an itty-bitty link is caused by no `width` or `height` attribute for `<video>`.  Given that you're not supposed to use those attributes in favor of CSS, it's kind of surprising.  I found that neither the javascript options of `defaultVideoWidth` or `videoWidth` will make the poster show (thusly, the itty-bitty link).  I haven't found another means of making this work.

Comment: @doubleJ : All you have to do is put a rule in your stylesheet for the can't play div. It has a class on it. Oh, and if you want a message about needing a plugin, you could add that in the MediaElement.js error callback.