# trouble with mediaelement.js and WMV

Tags: mediaelement.js, wmv

I am having a tough time with mediaelement.js and WMV sources. It says that is supports WMV but I cannot get it to work at all. I have my source set to a working WMV file, but when I open the webpage, I see the mediaelement screen, poster image, play button and controls, but when I click the play button nothing happens. What are the steps to use a WMV source file?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: See [How do I get the Silverlight player to work in Mediaelement.js][1]
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10233560/how-do-i-get-the-silverlight-player-to-work-in-mediaelement-js

Answer (score 2):

You need to add two lines of JavaScript before you convert the video tag to MediaElement.

```
mejs.plugins.silverlight[0].types.push('video/x-ms-wmv');
mejs.plugins.silverlight[0].types.push('audio/x-ms-wma');
```

This will get Windows Media video and audio to play on computers using MediaElement's Silverlight plugin.

Comment: As claimed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13257202/mediaelementjs-how-to-get-a-wmv-file-to-play) mediaelement.js assumes the mime type to be `video/wmv`. It works with this (wrong) mime type.