# mediaelementjs - How to get a wmv file to play

Tags: video, html5-video, wmv

I have tried

```
    <video width="640" height="360" id="player1" >
        <source type="video/x-ms-wmv" src="video/640p.wmv" />
    </video>

    <script>
    $('#player1').mediaelementplayer({
            plugins: ['flash','silverlight'],
            pluginPath: 'video/build/',
            flashName: 'flashmediaelement.swf',
            silverlightName: 'silverlightmediaelement.xap'
        });
    </script>
```

but when this renders out I get a Download File link. 
How do I get the silverlight control to fire and play the file?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer
it turns out the current version of mediaelementjs assumes wmv files have a mime type of 'video/wmv' the 'video/x-ms/wmv' mime type is not recognized as a wmv file